# How to consolidate data in google sheet using query function

Tags: google-sheets

Hell, 
I encountered one problem while combining different sheets(tabs) into one master sheet, e.g I have three sheets named Cola, Pepsi & Thumbsup, I consolidated their results all in my Master sheet using Query formula with null. Whenever anyone entered data in Cola, Pepsi & Thumbsup sheet it comes to my master sheet somewhere in Between the rows. I need it to comes queue wise, is it possible?
The problem I faced is, I am writing a remark on my master sheet on each entry so whenever someone added new data in Cola, Pepsi & Thumbsup it inserted in between the data and break the sequence of my remarks.
The remark I wrote for e.g Cola 103  it shift to cola 102 when someone enters new data in cola sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the query, it just displays the values. It's kind of impossible to control as your mention. I recommend to use app-script (macro), function `append` or `getValue` `setValue` or `getRange` `copyto` as text paste not just display

If your data have timestamp each row. It might work, sort by depending on date and time added. Need to use just one column sorted. In function query `...order by A asc`

Anyways, I still recommend to use app-script (macro)